# reload page when item selected in <select> - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, shtml

I have a small issue regarding the use of a `<select></select>`

I receive data from a server with an request. For this request I used shtml.

Now what I want is that when an user selects an item in de **selectbox** the page gets the data of that item from the server. An request to the server can look like this `%! tcp-connections`

So what I think i have to do is an page refresh with **JavaScript** or something like that. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option selected>Default</option>
    <option value="refresh">Refresh</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onchange(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.value === 'refresh') {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', onchange);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w425208t/**

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href = yourUrl;` It will "redirect" you to page with url `yourUrl`

Answer (score 1):

you can use any of these :

```
window.location.reload(false); 
// If we needed to pull the document from
//  the web-server again (such as where the document contents
//  change dynamically) we would pass the argument as 'true'.
//i.e. 'true' will force the page to reload from the server. 'false' will reload from cache, if available.

or 

location.reload(); 

or 

window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
```